Loading neural net model made with pytorch in R through the torch package
I've build a neural net (NN) in python using pytorch and I am trying to load it in R using the torch package. However, I get an error.
Here is a reproducible example. The NN is base on the example found at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html.
import torch
import math

x = torch.linspace(-math.pi, math.pi, 2000)
y = torch.sin(x)

p = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
xx = x.unsqueeze(-1).pow(p)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(3, 1),
    torch.nn.Flatten(0, 1)
)

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(2000):
    y_pred = model(xx)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)

    if t % 100 == 99:
        print(t, loss.item())

    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in model.parameters():
            param -= learning_rate * param.grad

torch.save(model, "test_save_pytorchNN.pth")

Once the model is saved, if I try to load it in R I get an error:
library(torch)
torch_load("test_save_pytorchNN.pth")
Error in rawToChar(raw_json) :
  embedded nul in string: '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\034\0\006\0test_save_pytorchNN/data.pklFB\002\0ZZ\x80\002ctorch.nn.modules.container\nSequential\nq\0)\x81q\001}q\002(X\b\0\0\0trainingq\003\x88X\v\0\0\0_parametersq\004ccollections\nOrderedDict\nq\005)Rq\006X\b\0\0\0_buffersq\ah\005)Rq\bX\033\0\0\0_non_persistent_buffers_setq\tc__builtin__\nset\nq\n]q\v\x85q\fRq\rX\023\0\0\0_backward_pre_hooksq\016h\005)Rq\017X\017\0\0\0_backward_hooksq\020h\005)Rq\021X\026\0\0\0_is_full_backward_hookq\022NX\016\0\0\0_forward_hooksq\023h\005)Rq\024X\032\0\0\0_forward_hooks_with_kwargsq\025h\005)Rq\026X\034\0\0\0_forward_hooks_always_calledq\027h\005)Rq\030X\022\0\0\0_forward_pre_hooksq\031h\005)Rq\032X\036\0\0\0_forward_pre_hooks_with_kwargsq\033h\005)Rq\034X\021\0\0\0_state_dict_hooksq\035h\005)Rq\036X\025\0\0\0_state_dict_pre_hooksq\037h\005)Rq X\032\0\0\0_load_state_dict_pre_hooksq!h\005)Rq"X\033\0\0\0_load_state_dict_post_hooksq#h\005)Rq$X\b\0\0\0_modulesq%h\005)Rq&(X\001\0\0\0

Any idea what is going on and if there is a way to fix that?  Could it be a question of version?
My python pytorch version is:
print(torch.__version__)
2.2.1+cu121

While the version of torch in R is 0.13.0 which seems to be using libtorch 2.0.1.
My R session info:
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.10.0

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
[4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

time zone: America/Toronto
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] torch_0.13.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] processx_3.8.2    bit_4.0.5         compiler_4.3.1    R6_2.5.1
[5] magrittr_2.0.3    cli_3.6.1         withr_2.5.0       safetensors_0.1.2
[9] Rcpp_1.0.11       bit64_4.0.5       coro_1.0.3        callr_3.7.3
[13] jsonlite_1.8.7    ps_1.7.5          rlang_1.1.1

Edit Following @kat's comment, I checked this documentation explaining how to import model files build in Python back into R, however it didn't help.  If I modify my RE to include the proposition:
In Python, I add the _use_new_zipfile_serialization=True parameter:
torch.save(model, "/data-temp/temp/test_save_pytorchNN_fix.pth", _use_new_zipfile_serialization=True)

Then in R, I can try to load the state dictionary:
state_dict <- load_state_dict("/data-temp/temp/test_save_pytorchNN_fix.pth")
Error in cpp_load_state_dict(path) : 
  Unpickler found unknown type torch.nn.modules.container.Sequential
Exception raised from readGlobal at /__w/torch/torch/src/lantern/src/Pickler.cpp:1002 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) + 0x6b (0x7f536e17705b in /home/dkf1688/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0xbf (0x7f536e171f6f in /home/dkf1688/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #2: torch::jit::LanternUnpickler::readGlobal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0xd17 (0x7f52d5437329 in /home/dkf1688/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/torch/lib/liblantern.so)

I still get an error.

Have you read this? In particular, under the heading "Loading models saved in python"...

@Kat, Thanks for your comment, sadly it didn't work.  You can see the edits in my question.
